# Seperate JavaFX GUI and Logic

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a game and thought of using JavaFx. What I want to do is from the main-class call a render-method repeatedly in the GUI-class (which contains all the javafx stuff start, scenes etc) and at the same time handle the game logic (collisiondetection etc) in the main-class. The problem is I'm getting a bunch of errors and it seems like they want the GUI-class to be the center of the application. So what I wonder is is my approach wrong?

Comment: Your approach is backwards.  The GUI is the center of the application.  Create a GUI model that doesn't know anything about JavaFX.  In the JavaFX GUI, read the model to create your GUI components, and update the model in your GUI controllers.  The model doesn't know anything about the GUI.  The GUI has to know about the model.  That way, you can use the same model with different GUIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX's main thread is the "application thread", which performs GUI functionality, and there is no circumventing this.

It is best to make your "GUI-class" contain the `start` and `main` methods as JavaFX requires, and then after creating your GUI objects, start a new thread that starts the entry point for your application logic. Even if, for some reason, you don't want to show the GUI when the app starts, you can call a method that performs `primaryStage.show()` for you after you've done other business logic.

You could still have your application logic call the GUI's render method every so often, and you could even make that yet another thread, or just use a timer. I don't think this is the paradigm, though. In any case you should use `Platform.runLater()` to make changes to your GUI, or it will end up hanging.

Comment: Alright thanks. The reason btw that I want to do this is encapsulation and having the abiltiy to change framework whenever, but I guess that doesn't work with javafx.

Comment: What do you mean by that? How does this stop you from using frameworks? In what way does this remove encapsulation?

Comment: Because everything is based around the javafx "application" and not the game-logic.

Comment: "Based around" is merely conceptual. All you really need to do is this: Whatever method you would normally consider to be the `main` method instead becomes the `run` method of a `Runnable` class. When the GUI starts a thread for your `Runnable`, its as if the app's entry point is the game logic, but the GUI just so happens to be already created. Even if you don't want to create the GUI first, you can still call methods in the GUI class which can dynamically build the GUI however your game logic defines it. Conceptually, then, the app is "based around" your game logic, with a GUI tacked on.

Comment: Yes I understand, I haven't worked with java GUIs too much. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Creating a multi-threaded application is orthogonal to separating GUI and logic.  It is not necessary to make the application multi-threaded in order to setup a layered architecture around design patterns such as MVC.  For new JavaFX developers I do not recommend writing multi-threaded code until it is absolutely necessary, and I do not see the necessity in this case.

Comment: An interesting perspective, because I've found that I've needed multi-threading for even simple JavaFX applications (outside of demos and tests of course). I don't find it a good idea to include business logic with GUI code. Display is a separate concern, as I see it.